# Found python launcher 3.5 in Apps & feature but can't find location

Tags: python

I'm trying to install anaconda so i'm uninstalling all python for a clean install.

I can't uninstall using the apps & feature since that has a different admin control and I can only uninstall using the uninstall software that comes along with python that is located in the python folder.

My problem is that, I can't find the folder where the 'Python Launcher' is located but it is still shown in the Apps & features list.

It also doesn't show when searched.

Comment: You generally don't need to delete other versions of Python for Anaconda. Anaconda does a good job living apart from other versions without conflicts.

Comment: @tom10 I'm having error saying 'activate.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command' when trying to open anaconda console. A solution i found said that some dependencies must have been the cause of the error so I'm trying to just eliminate all possible errors for me to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Even after re-installing, the error persists but i accidentally found a solution for this by restarting and re-installing Anaconda.